# Validate time (h:mm) on Regex

Tags: regex

I am validating h:mm and I need to have a max time 8:00.

Now the max value user can write is 7:59, but I need it to be 8:00.

My regex code:
/^([0-8]|([0-7]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9]))$/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand correctly, here is my solution:
^([0-7]:[0-5][0-9])|(8:00)$